# gsub with "|" character in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a data frame with strings under a variable with the `|` character. What I want is to remove anything downstream of the `|` character.

For example, considering the string

```
heat-shock protein hsp70, putative | location=Ld28_v01s1:1091329-1093293(-) | length=654 | sequence_SO=chromosome | SO=protein_coding
```

I wish to have only:

```
heat-shock protein hsp70, putative
```

Do I need any escape character for the `|` character?

If I do:

```
a <- c("foo_5", "bar_7")
gsub("*_.", "", a)
```

I get:

```
[1] "foo" "bar"
```

i.e. I am removing anything downstream of the `_` character.

However, If I repeat the same task with a `|` instead of the `_`:

```
b <- c("foo|5", "bar|7")
gsub("*|.", "", a)
```

I get:

```
[1] "" ""
```

Comment: `gsub("*_.", "", a)` is removing *one character* downstream of `_`. To remove *anything* downstream of `_`, use `gsub("_.*", "", a)`. And yes, you need to escape any regex special character (google for a list) with two backslashes, so anything downstream of a pipe is `gsub("\\|.*", "", a)`. (And a `*` at the beginning is meaningless.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to scape `|` by adding `\\|`. Try this

```
> gsub("\\|.*$", "", string)
[1] "heat-shock protein hsp70, putative "
```

where `string` is

```
string <- "heat-shock protein hsp70, putative | location=Ld28_v01s1:1091329-1093293(-) | length=654 | sequence_SO=chromosome | SO=protein_coding"
```

This alternative remove the space at the end of line in the output

```
 gsub("\\s+\\|.*$", "", string)
[1] "heat-shock protein hsp70, putative"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better job for `strsplit` than for a `gsub`

And yes, it looks like the pipe does need to be escaped.

```
string <- "heat-shock protein hsp70, putative | location=Ld28_v01s1:1091329-1093293(-) | length=654 | sequence_SO=chromosome | SO=protein_coding"
strsplit(string, ' \\| ')[[1]][1]
```

That outputs

```
"heat-shock protein hsp70, putative"
```

Note that I'm assuming you only want the text from before the first pipe, and that you want to drop the space that separates the pipe from the piece of the string you care about.

Comment: What's the advantage of `strsplit` over `gsub`? Seems like more overhead.

Comment: Seeing @Jilber Urbina's answer, I'm inclined to agree.  I initially thought this because whenever I'm struggling to get a regex based solution to do what I want, I look for ways to do it without regex.  "Give me the whole piece of a string up to a specific character" is very easy to get working with `strsplit`, and less error prone because it doesn't require writing a complex regex.  That said, this isn't a "complex regex," so I recant.  `gsub` approach is better I think.